# Run mysql commands on wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, mariadb

I have a script file (.sql) which has almost 20k insert statements in it. 
The sql file converted from a csv file. There's an option "load data infile" but it's disabled by the hosting company so i choose to upload a .sql file. As far as i learned, load data infile is not working with sql files. so i need to work like that command below on wordpress.

```
mysql < yourfile.sql
```

but there's another problem. The customer is not sharing the database information with me so i only have an editor page of wordpress and $wpdb object with me. My main objective is update a table with given csv file.
Database is a some version of MariaDB.

Comment: is there some reason you can't just open the file and execute the SQL in a PHP loop?

Comment: i have some performance issues. since it's a shared hosting and not much source assigned to the wp application, uploading at least 20k data might crash or something.

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP constants defined in `wp-config.php` file to get access to the database. To import the table you can use `exec` command from PHP file:

```
exec('mysql -u '.DB_USER.' -p'.DB_PASSWORD.' '.DB_NAME.' table_name < path/to/table_dump.sql;');
```

Change `table_name` to your table name. Without `table_name` parameter data will be imported for all tables in `DB_NAME` (if `table_dump.sql` contains commands for another tables).

If the table is not empty, then you must have a backup of the table or database in case you need to restore the table after import.

Comment: hope that works, I heard `shared hosting` and they usually disallow execs

Comment: Huh?  I'm asking you...try a simple exec to see, example one of my `godaddy` accounts doesn't allow `shell_exec`

Comment: It was not a question:) ok, then you can use [Adminer](https://www.adminer.org/) script for import.